# How to detect image height when using translateX

Tags: css, reactjs

So basically I have this carousel component in react:

```
const Carousel = (props) => {
    const {children} = props;
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const [length, setLength] = useState(children.length);
    const [touchPosition, setTouchPosition] = useState(null);

    return (
    <div className="carousel-content-wrapper" onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}>
        <div className="carousel-content" style={{ transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`, width: 'inherit' }}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
```

It is called by a component like this:

```
<Carousel>
    <img src="img1" alt="placeholder" />
    <img src="img2" alt="placeholder" />
</Carousel>
```

The trick here to switch between images is to change the X using css translateX.
What I need is to put a an icon at the bottom left corner of the picture.
Adding an icon and giving it:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
```

works. But for the first image. Because it looks like css set the Y acccording the current displayed image.
When I move the next image, if it has not exactly the same height, then the icon will not be positioned at

```
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
```

Or, it will. But that position is not longer the bottom left of the picture that now has another height.

Is there a way to recalculate things when image goes next or prev and reposition the left bototm corner?
I read a little bit about using ref, but IM not sure this can be accomplished here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Styled-Components:

Send the `const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] React.useState(0);` useState via props to `<Carousel/>` so we can create it elsewhere.

Create a `<CarouselImage/>` styled-component that is basically the `<img>` you are using.

Next, send the `currentIndex` variable as a prop into that component.

In the CSS part of `<CarouselImage currentIndex={currentIndex}/>`, add this:

```
transform: ${({ currentIndex }) => (currentIndex ? `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`)}
```

This will work because it'll force the X button to follow along with your `translateX` shenanigans in the Carousel component.

I find it to be an ugly hack, but it'll work as a quick thing for you. You can later explore more maintainable options.